# Inline namespaces and ambigous declarations

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, language-lawyer

I'm wondering if this is allowed:

```
namespace A {
  inline namespace B {
    int a;
  }
  int a;
}

void foo() {
  A::a = 0; // clang 3.4 compiles, but gcc doesn't
}
```

Standard says, that

> Finally, looking up a name in the enclosing namespace via explicit
>   qualification (3.4.3.2) will include members of the inline namespace
>   brought in by the using-directive even if there are declarations of
>   that name in the enclosing namespace.

But I can't get it.

Comment: Neither `gcc 4.9` nor `clang 3.5` allow this code, you can try on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/) ... `clang 3.4` does though, seems like a bug

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thank you, Shafik. It's wonderful resource. Yes, I tried this code at my job, here I have clang-3.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this was a [pre clang 3.5 bug](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html#812) and there are two defect reports on this [812](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#812) and [861](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#861). The resolution is in 861 and adds the following to `3.4.3.2`  *[namespace.qual]* (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> For a namespace X and name m, the namespace-qualified lookup set S(X,m) is defined as follows: Let S'(X,m) be the set of all declarations of m in X and the inline namespace set of X (7.3.1 [namespace.def]). If S'(X,m) is not empty, S(X,m) is S'(X,m); otherwise, S(X,m) is the union of S(Ni,m) for all non-inline namespaces Ni nominated by using-directives in X and its inline namespace set.

and the also relevant additions:

> if S(X,m) is the empty set, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, if S(X,m) has exactly one member, or if the context of the reference is a using-declaration (7.3.3 [namespace.udecl]), S(X,m) is the required set of declarations of m. **Otherwise if the use of m is not one that allows a unique declaration to be chosen from S(X,m), the program is ill-formed.**

It looks like the change was added pre C++11, this text is present in [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).